# external diff tool meld not working with svn

Tags: bash, svn

I have configured the following in the ~/.subversion/config to use the meld as difftool.
by adding the following line 
diff-cmd=svnmeld

then added the following in the /usr/bin/svnmeld with executable path.

```
#!/bin/bash
meld "$6" "$7"
```

But then i try to a diff on a file in the svn repo, i still donot see the meld being lauched.

I am using the subversion, 1.8.5..

Any idea, what might have gone wrong ?

I have tried calling the meld directly, on command line like
svn diff diff-cmd=meld file.cpp which works fine..

thanks a lot

Comment: edit your script to inlude the full path to `meld`, ie. `/my/path/to/bin/meld` and see if that solves the current prooblem. If so then in your env files, you'll want to add `PATH="$PATH":/my/path/to/bin". Good luck.

Comment: thanks..tried but no luck :( . Can it be subversion config is ignoring this command. How to debug this ?

Comment: can some svn experts please help

Comment: unusual to have `#/bin/bash` followed by references to `$6 & $7`. if they are $6 & $7 in a wrapper script, and you're only calling diff-cmd with 2 args, try changing above to $1 and $2. Or maybe you understand and are sure about that, so you can ignore this idea. Not an svn expert. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, but i tried calling this directly on command line like :svn diff file.cpp --diff-cmd=meld "$6" "$7". And this works like magic calling the diff with the meld. It looks like the svn config is the issue here ..Svn experts can throw some light on how to debug this further

Comment: looks like putting this line in the [helpers] section of the config file solved this issue !. I was putting this at the end of the config file under the [auto-props]. Not sure why though !

Comment: post your solution as an answer, and you can accept your own answer after 2 days, giving you more reputation points. Glad you found the solution to your problem.

Comment: add `set -xv` underneath the shebang to see what your script is doing. And you can see what parameters your script receives: `printf "%s\n" "$@"`, or `for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${!i}"; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like putting this line in the [helpers] section of the config file solved this issue !. I was putting this at the end of the config file under the [auto-props].